# NotFoundHttpException in laravel 4

Tags: php, symfony, laravel-4

I have a route defined like this to sign out under routes.php

```
Route::group(array("before" => "auth"), function(){

    Route::get('/sign-out', array(
        'as' => 'user-sign-out',
        'uses' => 'AccountController@getSignOut'
    ));
 });
```

Next I have a view setup like this inside `views/page/home/home-header.blade.php`

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li><a href={{ URL::route('user-sign-out') }} class="text-nav">Sign out</a></li>
</ul>
```

Next I have included the above `view in my home.blade.php` inside the views folder:

```
@section('header')
    @include('page.home.home-header')
@stop
```

Now clicking on the `sign-out` link returns `NotFoundHttpException` and if I directly include the `<li><a href={{ URL::route('user-sign-out') }} class="text-nav">Sign out</a></li>` in my `home.blade.php` it works all right.

Comment: Can you try @include('page.home.home-header') in your home.blade.php?

Comment: Yup I did tr it! In fact the path name was complete. I had made a mistake while posting. So can someone tell me what is going wrong here?

Comment: so what is given for the sign-out link on the view?

Comment: Can you double check the link generated is correct when the page is rendered and also post any routes that are *above* this sign out route. Sometimes if you define deeper routes first, especially when using `Route::controller`, you'll run into a number of issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
href="{{ URL::route('user-sign-out') }}"
```

check double quotes..